# How To Calculate The Average Of Unique Values In One Column Using DAX Query?

Tags: excel, dax

I just want to calculate the average of distinct values in one column. just like i have a column having sales values .
2
2
3
3
4
4
5
5 
i want the distinct value average like ((2+3+4+5)/8 )   . distinct values divided by total number of values . result should be 1.8 .
thanks in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You have an "excel" tag, do you want to do this in excel? If so then with data in `A1:A10` you can use this array formula

`=SUM(IF(MATCH(A1:A10,A1:A10,0)=ROW(A1:A10)-MIN(ROW(A1:A10))+1,A1:A10))/COUNT(A1:A10)`

confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: dear barry i want to do in DAX TOO. Thanks for your help but i really need it in DAX .